# Looping through table rows and accessing data via class name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table format. the rows are generated using two for loops:

```
<table id="tableMain">
    <tr id = "uniqueID1" class = "firstClass">
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio1' value='0' class='myradio'>"</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio1' value='1' class='myradio'>"</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id = "uniqueID2" class = "secondClass">
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio2' value='2' class='myradio1'>"</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio2' value='3' class='myradio1'>"</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio2' value='4' class='myradio1'>"</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id = "uniqueID3" class = "thirdClass">
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio3' value='5' class='myradio2'>"</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio3' value='6' class='myradio2'>"</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio3' value='7' class='myradio2'>"</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio3' value='8' class='myradio2'>"</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, the tr ID is unique for each row through out the whole table but the class name are different each time the loop goes out of the inner loop.. so it creates a kind of group within the table but still unique rowsIDs.

My question is how do I access the selected values at each row according to the class name and get the value at each.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
var rows=[];
$('#myForm tr').each(function(){
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    if( rows.indexOf(id) ==-1){ /* push to array if it doesn't exist */
        rows.push( id);
    }
});
var totalUnique= rows.length;
alert("Total Number of Comparison = " + totalUnique);
});
```

Is there a way to fetch each 'class' result into an array, do something with the result and then do the same for the rest..? i.e enter table body n look for first class, loop through and get the selected values on each row and then do same for rest?

Comment: are you trying to get the data for one row or all rows?

Comment: the selected value at the row or all possible values?

Comment: I am trying to get the data from all the rows but fetched class by class i.e. one class may have 2 td and others may have more. so I would like to group them in my result

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You do not show that "the tr ID is unique through out the whole table" and you undo my edits to make it correct. Your code will not wok unless you actually have unique id's.

Comment: sorry that was my mistake! the ids are meant to be unique but sets of tds can share the same class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your seconde question , here is a code to get values of each tr row :

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hMtkc/)

```
function rowsValues(){
 $("#tableMain tr").each(function(index,value){
    var rowValues=new Array(); 
    $(this).find('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
    rowValues.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
   }) 
      alert("row"+index+" : "+rowValues);
     //do something with rowValues
 } 
)}
```

to get the sum , Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xNMA2/)

```
function SUM(){
    var sum=0;
    $("#tableMain").find('input:radio:checked').each(function(){sum+= parseInt($(this).val());});
    return sum;
}

$("#btn").click(function(){alert(SUM());});
```

PS: Close your `<td></td>` correctly

Answer (score 1):

While creating your table, if you store the classes in an array will greatly simplify this

```
/* stored while creating table*/
var rowClasses=['class_1','class_2'....];

$.each(rowClasses , function(i, className){       
   var thisClassRadioArray=$('tr.'+className +':radio:checked').map(function(){
           return this.value
   }).get()
})
```

Comment: could you please provide me with a fiddle. I think this is what I need but not sure what you mean by storing my class in an array when creating table. thanks

Comment: well you said you dynamically create the table with `for` loops...assumed was in javascript no? If so, while you create class...push to an array

Comment: I created it using PHP since i'm really poor with jquery. will it still be possible?

Comment: sure...put a script tag near table and echo a javascript variable with json_encode of your array collected in php

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$("button").on("click", function ()
{
    var value = 0;

    $("#tableMain").find("tr").each(function () 
    {
        value += parseInt( $(this).find(".myradio:checked").val() );
    }); 

    alert( value );
});
```

[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x55aA/)

I had to alter your HTML, as it wasn't valid:

```
<table id="tableMain">
    <tr id="uniqueID1" class="firstClass">
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio1' value='0' class='myradio' />0</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio1' value='1' class='myradio' />1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="uniqueID2" class="secondClass">
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio2' value='2' class='myradio' />2</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio2' value='3' class='myradio' />3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="uniqueID3" class="thirdClass">
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio3' value='4' class='myradio' />4</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='radio3' value='5' class='myradio' />5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button>Calculate</button>
```

Comment: thanks scott. but is there a way to fetch each 'class' result into an array, do something with the result and then do the same for the rest..? i.e enter table body n look for first class, loop through and get the selected values on each row and then do same for rest?

Answer (score 0):

I did it so you can access each of the classes independently from an object. the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jyYPM/2/

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var AllObjects = [];
    $('#tableMain tr').each(function(){
        var thisClassData = {};
        thisClassData.ClassName = $(this).attr('class');
        thisClassData.Values = [];
        $(this).find('input:checked').each(function() {
            thisClassData.Values.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });
        AllObjects.push(thisClassData)
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(AllObjects));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** your HTM is invalid. Don't use the same ID for different elements:

[Id reference in w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)
On "Definition and usage": The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

This could make the jQuery scripts fail. Please, solve this problem first!!

Apart form this, charaf jra's answer is perfect.

Comment: Express more clearly and show more realistic sample code. If I read "Basically, the tr ID is unique through out the whole table" I understand it, as you say it: the ID is unique for all the table (not for each row in the table) Besides, the sample code shows the same id for each row. I'd recommend you to change your text ("the Id is unique for each row in the table") and change the sample HTML (for example: 'UniqueID1', ''UniqueID2', ''UniqueID3' and so on). Isn't it much more clear?

Comment: there isn't a solution one in this post that even uses the ID...sure getting excited over nothing

Comment: The solution is in charaf jra's answer.

Comment: Believe it or not, this could be a solution if the repeated IDs were causign a problem. Repeating IDs causes different kind of problems with different browsers adn JavaScripts. As you don't edit your question, I'll edit it for you.

Comment: No more comments. Now the question has a better redaction than the original one, you like it or not.